# Sanity check about basic abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In the following I am talking about algebras over $\mathbb C$ and ideals. An ideal is called modular if there is $u \in A$ so that for all $a \in A$ both $a-ua$ and $a-au$ are in the ideal $I$. I read that if $A$ is unital then all its ideals are modular and therefore $A$ has maximal ideals. I get that if $A$ has a unit then all its ideals are modular. What I don't get is: there is a theorem, Krull's theorem, which states that every ring has a maximal ideal and as far as I can tell Krull's theorem is applicable to algebras too and therefore it should hold that every algebra has a maximal ideal whether it has a unit or not. Please can someone help me with this and tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krull's Theorem actually states that every non-zero *unital* ring has a maximal ideal. The unital condition is often omitted, typically by texts that deal only with unital rings (or include the existence of a multiplicative identity as part of their definition of rings), and so don't mention the condition.